# Using Gradle execute for wix

Tags: groovy, wix, gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle that compiles my project, runs test creates a jar then packages that with launch4j. I want to be able to use wix to create a installer as well, however I seem to be having a lot of trouble launching it from .execute().

The files necessary for candle and light are held in \build\installer. However trying to access those files by calling execute in the build file is always met with failure.

I have made a second build.gradle in /build/installer that does work. It is:

```
task buildInstaller {

def command = project.rootDir.toString() + "//" +"LSML Setup.wxs"
def candleCommand = ['candle', command]    
def candleProc = candleCommand.execute()
candleProc.waitFor()
def lightCommand = ['light' , '-ext', 'WixUIExtension', "LSML Setup.wixobj"]
def lightProc = lightCommand.execute()


}
```

Is there some way I can run the second build file from the main one and have it work or is there a way to call execute directly and have it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project consist of few gradle builds (gradle projects) you should use dependencies. Working with `execute()` method is a bad idea. I will do it in this way:

ROOT/candle/candle.gradle

```
task build(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/C', 'candle.exe', '...'
}
```

ROOT/app/build.gradle

```
task build(dependsOn: ':candle:build') {
    println 'build candle'
}
```

ROOT/app/settings.gradle

```
include ':candle'
project(':candle').projectDir = "$rootDir/../candle" as File
```

BTW I had problems with `Exec` task so in my projects I replaced it with `and.exec()` so candle task may look like this:

```
task candle << {
    def productWxsFile = new File(buildDir, "Product.wxs")
    ant.exec(executable:candleExe, failonerror: false, resultproperty: 'candleRc') {
        arg(value: '-out')
        arg(value: buildDir.absolutePath+"\\")
        arg(value: '-arch')
        arg(value: 'x86')
        arg(value: '-dInstallerDir='+installerDir)
        arg(value: '-ext')
        arg(value: wixHomeDir+"\\WixUtilExtension.dll")
        arg(value: productWxsFile)
        arg(value: dataWxsFile)
        arg(value: '-v')

    }
    if (!ant.properties['candleRc'].equals('0')) {
        throw new Exception('ant.exec failed rc: '+ant.properties['candleRc'])
    }
}
```

More informations about multi projects you will find here http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html.

Answer (score 0):

The [SetupBuilder plugin](https://github.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder) can do the job. It create the lauch4j launcher for your java application, signed it, create the msi file and signed it. You does not need to work with the complex WIX toolset syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My post comes very late but wanted to share my feedback as this chat was very helpful for me. For my case, I had to add the last to lines of code to generate the installer.

`task buildInstaller {`

`def command = project.rootDir.toString() + "//" +"LSML Setup.wxs"`

`def candleCommand = ['candle', command]`

`def candleProc = candleCommand.execute()`

`candleProc.waitFor()`

`def lightCommand = ['light', '-ext', 'WixUIExtension', "LSML Setup.wixobj"]`

`def lightProc = lightCommand.execute()`

`lightProc`

`lightProc.waitFor()`

`}`

This task generates three files ("LSML Setup.wixobj", "LSML Setup.wixpdb" and, "LSML Setup.msi")